How to list all files and folders of a file or directory target in Python?
Function Description
I am trying to write a function which takes an input target which is a target to a path on the filesystem. It could be a directory itself, or it could be a file.
This function should return a list of all files and folders which are sub-targets below target.
To explain in more detail:

If target is a file, the return value is a list of length 1 with the fully qualified path of target.
If target is a directory, the return value should be a list containing the recursive sub-contents of target, including target itself.
Items should be returned in sorted order
Items should be returned in such a way that it is possible to distinguish between which returned items are paths to files and which returned items are paths to directorys.

Existing Questions on Stack Overflow
There are similar questions on Stack Overflow, but none cover this case.
Here is a short summary:

How do I list all files of a directory?

Getting a list of all subdirectories in the current directory


The answers under both question assume the target is a directory. They do not work if the target is a file. Additionally, in the first question, only files are returned. Not directories. In the second question, only directories are returned. Not files.
Strategy for Implementation
This function should be broken down into three steps.

The first step should obtain the relative paths.
The second step should be a map operation which converts the relative paths to absolute, or fully-qualified, paths.
The third steps should sort the returned items.

This design will offer a high-degree of flexibility, such that each function does one job and functions are composable. This is good software design, some would call it a clean design.
An arguably better design might split the collection of files and directories into two independent functions, however this would result in lower performance as the target will have to be walked twice.
Choice of base function
There are several choices of base function of which I am aware. We have:

os.listdir
os.scandir
os.walk
os.fwalk
Maybe others?

I am not sure exactly which might be the best choice.
Attempted Solution
I started off trying to implement this. It's quite complicated because the input needs to be a target path, and the whether this is a file or directory is not initially known.
This means the logic of the interface level needs to be different to the recursive calls.
I can't figure out a simple or elegant solution to this. That makes me think there is probably a better way to do it, I just can't see what that is.
Building on this example:
import os

def fast_scandir(target_dir: str) -> list[str]:
    items = []
    for f in os.scandir(target_dir):
        if f.is_dir():
            items.extend(fast_scandir(f.path))
        if f.is_file():
            items.append(f.path)
    items.sort()
    return items

Which is a simple solution, but does not implement all the requirements, I came up with this:
# Interface level, takes a `target`, don't know if it is a file or dir
def fast_scandir_3(target:str) -> list[tuple[str, str]]:
    items:list[tuple[str, str]] = []
    if os.path.isfile(target):
        item = ('f', target)
        items.extend(_fast_scandir_3_impl(item))
    elif os.path.isdir(target):
        item = ('d', target)
        items.extend(_fast_scandir_3_impl(item))
    return items

This (below) is just nasty. It is excessively complicated, hard to read, and hard to understand. There must be a more straightforward approach to this.
# Implementation layer
# TODO: will add sorting with `sorted` and fully-qualified paths later
def _fast_scandir_3_impl(target:tuple[str, str]) -> list[tuple[str, str]]:
    items:list[tuple[str, str]] = []
    items.append(target)
    if target[0] == 'f':
        pass
    elif target[0] == 'd':
        target_path = target[1]
        for subtarget in os.listdir(target_path):
            if os.path.isfile(subtarget):
                target = ('f', subtarget)
                items.extend(_fast_scandir_3_impl(target))
            elif os.path.isdir(subtarget):
                target = ('d', subtarget):
                items.extend(_fast_scandir_3_impl(target ))
    return items

Idea for implementing the fully-qualified paths:
def _fast_scandir_3_fully_qualified_impl(target:tuple[str, str]) -> list[tuple[str, str]]:
    return (
        list(
            map(
                lambda item: (item[0], os.path.abspath(item[1])),
                _fast_scandir_3_impl(target),
            )
        )
    )

Idea for implementing sorting:
def _fast_scandir_3_fully_qualified_sorted_impl(target:tuple[str, str]) -> list[tuple[str, str]]:
    return sorted(_fast_scandir_3_fully_qualified_impl(target), key=lambda pair: pair[1])

The most significant issue being this doesn't actually do what it is supposed to do.
In addition, some further questions remain:

Is this implementation with listdir the right choice?
Is sorted the most efficient way to sort the returned items? (Not shown in above implementation.)


Python's pathlib module is well suited to this problem. In particular, you can utilise its rglob() (recursive glob) feature.
For sorting the results just use the built-in sorted() function.
Something like this:
from pathlib import Path

def scan_dir(target: Path) -> list[tuple[str, str]]:
    target = target.expanduser().resolve()
    if target.is_file():
        return [("f", str(target))]
    result: list[tuple[str, str]] = []
    if target.is_dir():
        result.append(('d', str(item)))
        for item in target.rglob("*"):
            if item.is_file():
                result.append(('f', str(item)))
            elif item.is_dir():
                result.append(('d', str(item)))
    return sorted(result, key=lambda t: t[1])

for t in scan_dir(Path(".")):
    print(*t)


What does .resolve() do here? The docs tell me that .expanduser() converts ~ into a fully qualified path.

I quite like this. Presumably rglob does all of the recusive stuff for you? I would also guess you cannot call rglob on a file directly, hence the outer layer with is_file and is_dir still required?

I'd have just stuck a '/ on the end of paths that are directories. It doesn't change the semantics of the path, and means you can just return a list[str]. eg. /file vs /dir/. It does change the sort order a little though . eg. '/dir' < '/dir.' < '/dir/', so you'd need to change how/when you sort the paths. Actually, I'd probably just have returned list[Path], since Path satisfies the requirement to tell if a returned value is a directory or not with its is_dir() function.

@user2138149 My understanding is that you want the absolute pathnames (in sorted order). By using resolve() we can allow for target being relative. The use of expanduser() just allows for a target that has a tilde prefix - i.e., rooted in the current user's HOME directory. Yes - rglob() handles all the recursion for you

@Dunes You are quite right that directories could just be presented with a trailing / and plain files without. The idea of using explicit indicators comes from the original post

@user2138149 Your edit of my answer is intriguing. Are you plannning to ignore sockets, block devices, fifos etc.?

@SIGHUP Yes - I've also added a line to store the current target itself in the case which it is a directory

@SIGHUP My actual code is now a hybrid of your answer the the answer by Daweo

import os

def fast_scandir(target: str) -> list[str]:
    items = []
    
    # Check if the target is a file
    if os.path.isfile(target):
        items.append(os.path.abspath(target))
    
    # Check if the target is a directory
    elif os.path.isdir(target):
        # Use os.walk to recursively list all files and directories
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(target):
            # Add directories and files to the list
            for name in dirs:
                items.append(os.path.join(root, name))
            for name in files:
                items.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    
    # Sort the items to maintain consistent order
    items.sort()
    
    return items
target = '/path/to/target'
result = fast_scandir(target)
for item in result:
    print(item)


This will not generate absolute paths when the target (function parameter) is a relative path. It also does not annotate each path to indicate if it's a plain file, directory or something else

@SIGHUP That's probably ok though, because I would guess OP is assuming I will add these functions to perform those operations later.

I propose different implementation using listdir namely
import os
def crawl(target, dirs=None, files=None):
    dirs = [] if dirs is None else dirs
    files = [] if files is None else files
    if os.path.isfile(target):
        files.append(os.path.abspath(target))
        return dirs, files
    elif os.path.isdir(target):
        dirs.append(os.path.abspath(target))
    for subpath in os.listdir(target):
        abspath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(target, subpath))
        crawl(abspath, dirs, files)
    return dirs, files

which is simple recursive function, which return 2-tuple of lists, one holding absolute paths to directories and one holding absolute paths to files.
If you are wondering about 2 first lines of function this is to avoid mutable argument gotcha.
No attempts are made to sort. Complexity of crawl function is 3 according to mccabe.

I like this - makes a lot of sense and provides a way to distinguish between the two types. Pretty good - thanks

Just a thought - rather than defaulting your arguments to None, can you default them to an empty [], and then remove the two if conditions?

@user2138149 do not that, unless you really known consequences of mutable default arguments

Ah - of course, forgot about that

Start of an Answer
I realized I was over-complicating this implementation by trying to get a list of tuples containing paths and a string indicating if each path is a file or directory first.
It would be much easier to split this into two steps.

Get all the paths, recursively
Convert the paths into tuples

Here is my current working implementation for this:
def _fast_scandir_3_impl_get_paths_recursive(target: str) -> list[str]:
    items:list[str] = []
    if os.path.isfile(target):
        items.append(target)
    elif os.path.isdir(target):
        items.append(target)
        for item in os.listdir(target):
           item = os.path.join(target, item)
           more_items = _fast_scandir_3_impl_get_paths_recursive(item)
           items.extend(more_items)
    return items


def _fast_scandir_3_impl_convert_paths_to_path_tuples(paths:list[str]) -> list[tuple[str, str]]:
    def path_to_tuple(path:str) -> tuple[str, str]:
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            return ('f', path)
        elif os.path.isdir(path):
            return ('d', path)

    return (
        list(
            map(
                path_to_tuple,
                paths,
            )
        )
    )


def _fast_scandir_3_impl_convert_path_tuples_to_fully_qualified_path_tuples(
    path_tuples:list[tuple[str, str]],
) -> list[tuple[str, str]]:
    return (
        list(
            map(
                lambda path_tuple: (path_tuple[0], os.path.abspath(path_tuple[1])),
                path_tuples,
            )
        )
    )


def _fast_scandir_3_impl_sort_path_tuples(
    path_tuples:list[tuple[str, str]],
) -> list[tuple[str, str]]:
    return (
        sorted(
            path_tuples,
            key=lambda path_tuple: path_tuple[1],
        )
    )


def fast_scandir_3(target:str) -> list[tuple[str, str]]:

    # get all paths
    paths = _fast_scandir_3_impl_get_paths_recursive(target)

    # convert paths to tuple depending on type
    path_tuples = _fast_scandir_3_impl_convert_paths_to_path_tuples(paths)

    # convert paths to fully qualified paths
    fully_qualified_path_tuples = (
        _fast_scandir_3_impl_convert_path_tuples_to_fully_qualified_path_tuples(
            path_tuples,
        )
    )

    # sort by fully qualified path
    sorted_fully_qualified_path_tuples = (
        _fast_scandir_3_impl_sort_path_tuples(fully_qualified_path_tuples)
    )

    return sorted_fully_qualified_path_tuples

However, this is likely to be pretty inefficient because for each path, os.isfile and os.isdir is called twice.

Did you consider my answer if only to see how you can minimise the function calls?

@SIGHUP currently looking at it - give me a few mins
